# Execute AutoOpen macro from custom .dotm template

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I need to create a document from custom template using command line. This template contains the `AutoOpen` routine and it is executing if I open the template itself:

```
path_to_msoffice/winword.exe "c:/users/michael/Application Data/Microsoft/Templates/my_template.dotm"
```

But when I'm trying to create a document based on the template, it is created but the macro routine is not executing:

```
path_to_msoffice/winword.exe /t"c:/users/michael/Application Data/Microsoft/Templates/my_template.dotm"
```

I have Office 2010, macro execution is allowed.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the /z switch instead of the /t switch. That enables the `NEW` event. (for a complete list of command line switches see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210565/how-to-use-startup-command-line-switches-to-start-word-2010-word-2007)

Please note that AutoOpen is *not* what you want when creating a new document from a template. That is what fires when an existing document linked to the template is opened.

AutoNew would be the macro that fires when a new document is created using File/New, but the /z switch triggers the `New` *event*, not that macro. You find the event in the template's `ThisDocument` (class) module. Click on the list at the top left of the Code Window and choose `Document`. Then choose `New`from the list at the top right to get the stub if Word doesn't create it automatically.